# How do I launch the network manager pop-up menu window displayed in attachment within Ubuntu 18.04 and LXDE?

Tags: networking, icons, top

I would like to know:

1. What is the name of the program that manages the network icon on the top bar of Ubuntu 18.04 with LXDE? The network icon I meant gets highlighted with a red circle on the attached screenshot.
2. What command line can be used to hide/unhide or enable/disable the mentioned network icon?
3. What command line can be used to display the pop-up menu window, of the network manager, that gets displayed when I click on this network icon? The window I mean gets displayed in the attached screenshot.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: What is your DE?

Comment: My development environment is LXDE.